# How can I make the Share This button to share the link it stays beside?

Tags: javascript

so is this Share This button which is doing a pretty good job except the fact that is not sharing the link is staying beside but the link of the page is staying on.

e.g. `StackOverflow Link`SHARE THIS button.

question: how can I make this button to share the link it stays beside, in this case, to share the StackOverflow Link?

I'm pretty much a newbie in JS so if someone can share the entire working code here will be appreciated :)

Thanks folks :)
VD

Comment: So you want a button with a link next to it, and when the button is clicked, it must share the link?

Comment: 1) Go to your profile 2) Scroll down to the list of your questions 3) `foreach(question in list) { clickit; AcceptAsAnswer(ClickGreenCheckMark); }`  ...the probability of someone answering your question has now increased. :-)

Comment: Exactly Nideo, I want the button to share the link. Can you help? Thx :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Thomas, I just marked a couple of questions as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your link is an anchor (`<a... />`) and your button is a button (`<input type="button" />`) you can wrap them both in a container and do something like this:

```
<div>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">link</a>  
  <input type="button" value="share link" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:button').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).parent().find('a').attr('href');
    // do something to share url.
  });
});
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/fallen888/PaJLT/2/